# Emulating a native USB stick within vmware

Tags: windows, usb, malware, emulator

I use a sandbox to test malware any analyse it.
One of the latest malware explicitly looks for USB-sticks to write code on it.
What I'd need is a little (windows) tool to emulate/fake a USB stick within the Win7 that acts like the malware victim, so the malware "thinks" it's real. That fake should not be recognised as fake to easy as the malware will not run then.
VMWare-tools usb-redirection is not an option as this implies VMWare tools installed and that is a nogo for the victim.

Thanks so much for your ideas...  :-)

Cheers
Marcus

Comment: Actually, anything that would do the job. The only constraint is, that it looks as real USB stick as possible to the malware. ;-)

Comment: Thx, in linux it would be much easier, but the malware rules the OS to be windows.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use ImDisk to create a virtual USB-drive to test your malware with.

Link to ImDisk Toolkit software: https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/

However I don't know if the malware will recognize this as fake or not.

Comment: Thanks Aulis, but as far as I understand the docs and the comments, this will not give me a USB mass storage device, but the malware looks for that kind of device.

Comment: You're welcome. It is possible, but I think you should try it anyway.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for ESXi. Thanks!